# New florescent fixture install

Tags: electrical

I just purchased a new florescent fixture with  a fancy plug connector, and I will be replacing an older fixture that is connected (twisted with wire nuts), so I have no place to plug the new fixture.  Can I just cut the fancy new plug off, and twist the fixture wires to the house wires, like the old fixture?
Thanks

Comment: Is it suspended or mounted to the ceiling? Could you attach a picture?

Comment: Any twisting of house wires must be done *inside a junction box*.  If you don't have a junction box, this is a codevio.  If you do have a junction box (commonly an "octagon box"), they make a lid for that box which has cutouts for a receptacle.  Total cost: $2.  Standard wiring for a lot of warehouse/industrial spaces.

Answer (score 1):

In the same situation , I put a receptacle in the ceiling fixture so T can simply plug in the new light and it would be easy to change fixtures in the future.